# Inserting value to textbox via using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, textbox

Hi im using googlemaps api to get  my location. It working flawlessly. And i am trying to insert its acquired longitude and latitude to my input box with using Jquery for further usage. When i try to use Jquery to edit my textbox there is no changes in my textbox even if i use static value. Here is my code bellow. I commented out non working part.

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
?>
<script>

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 12
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

  // Try HTML5 geolocation.
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

        //THIS PART IS NOT WORKING
        $('#tb1').val(lat);
        $('#tb2').val(lng);
        $('#tb2').val('test');


      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }
}



function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                        'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key= AIzaSyAwFgO9_-PfY3KufIH-8vgHeBR8sdpZ_VQ&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"
        async defer>
    </script>

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

    });
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<label>GIS</label>
</div>
<div id="body">

    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 20%;
        widhth: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
   <div id="map"></div>
  <body>




    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="textbox" name="tb1" id='tb1'/>
    <input type="textbox" name="tb2" id='tb2'/>
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <button type="submit" name="btn-upload">upload</button>
    </form>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should be $('#tb1').val(lat); not var.

Comment: Sorry i writed it wrong it is val in original code and not working either.

Comment: Where are you declaring lat & lag?

Comment: Im trying to get it from google api in above line. And its not working even if i add static value like 'test'

Comment: Add var lat = 0; lng = 0; inside if (navigator.geolocation) { the rest of the code looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no **lat** or **lng** value at that point.

What you have is a **pos** object that have two properties: **lat** and **lng**.

```
var pos = {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude
  };
```

So you shoud use:

```
    //THIS PART SHOULD WORK NOW
    $('#tb1').val(pos.lat);
    $('#tb2').val(pos.lng);
```

Comment: No differences. It is not working for 'test' case either.

Comment: I just noted that your script code is before the html part. Try to put your <script>....</script> element after the <html></html> one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$('#tb1').var(lat);
```

use:

```
$('#tb1').val(pos.lat);
```

Comment: Also you have `type="textbox"` instead of `type="text"`

Comment: @Furkan `lat` is undefined, isn't it ? You store latitude in `pos.lat`. Check my edit.

Comment: $('#tb1').val(pos.lat);
   $('#tb2').val(pos.lng);
   $('#tb2').val('test');
   
   
   i change it like that but still not working. Should it be work for at least for 'test' case?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is causing from

there is no

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```